# Rails Routing Issue, route not found initally, but on page refresh it works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am relatively new to rails and could not find an answer to this.I have added a controller with a corresponding view. When I go to

root/order_build/show?build=1

I get a routing error saying the path is not found, this is when I click on a link with that address. After I get to the error page and manually refresh the page it works. Any idea why this would be happening?

```
class OrderBuildController < ApplicationController
  def show
     @build= Build.find(request.GET["build"])

  end

  def order
  end

  def index
  end
end
```

Here is my routing file

```
ProjectD::Application.routes.draw do
  get "order_build/show"

  get "order_build/order"

  get "order_build/index"

  get "home/index"

  #root :to => "home#index"
  root :controller => 'home', :action => :index
  resources :users, :user_sessions
  match 'login' => 'user_sessions#new', :as => :login
  match 'logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
  resources :sessions

  resources :providers

  resources :build_prices


  resources :products do
    resources :product_images
  end

  resources :product_tags_products

  resources :product_tags

  resources :product_images

  resources :orders

  resources :order_statuses

  resources :build_prices

  resources :builds do
    resources :build_prices
  end


  resources :build_statuses

  resources :account_types
end
```

Comment: can you paste the exact error you are getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to associate your route with the corresponding controller

So, instead of:

```
get "order_build/show"
```

You will do this:

```
match "/order_build/show" => "order_build#show"
```

This way you are associating your /order_build/show route with the show method on your order_build controller.

Comment: Better use `get` than `match`. The latter is going to be deprecated.

Comment: That was it thanks! I was confused on the difference between the two but now it makes sense.